# Bower - multiple versions of angular

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm working on an angular app that uses bower for dependency management. At the moment I'm getting the following error in my browser console:

Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function

From researching this a bit, it seems that I likely have two different versions of angular in use and that's the cause of the error. However, I've used `bower list` and it looks like angular and all of the packages that list angular as a dependency are using the same version: 1.4.14

In the bower.json file, angular is listed as: `"angular": "~1.4.9"` under both dependencies and resolutions.

How can I track down where another version of angular is being used? Or could there be something else causing this issue?

Note: this app runs fine on another computer, which is why I'm convinced it's a version issue.

Comment: `angular.module(...).info` is not a function - If `module()` is not a function then perhaps you're not loading **angular.js** at all?

Comment: `angular.module(...).info()` didn't become a feature until version 1.6.3. ([Changelogs for 1.6.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#163-scriptalicious-bootstrapping-2017-03-08))

Comment: @AlonEitan `module()` is a function and is not causing the error. `module().info` is not a function because it's undefined in AngularJS v1.4.14. So in the code there's a line that's trying to call `angular.module(...).info()`

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren Can you please reference to this function in the official [api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/)? I can't find it and didn't know it exist (At least as a function, as the OP is not calling a function - i.e `.info()`, but as property `.info`)

Comment: @AlonEitan [Official API reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/docs/api/ng/type/angular.Module)

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren, so then the issue is that one of the packages I'm using requires a newer version of angular? Did this not come up when I ran `bower install` because of the entry in "resolutions"?

Comment: You'd have to check where this angular.module(...).info() gets called. Then you can check whether or not that dependency recently updated without checking if the version is supported.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren, thanks! The ngCookies module is where the issue was. I updated my bower.json file from `"angular-cookies": "^1.5.5"` to `"angular-cookies": "~1.5.5"` and once it installed an older version, everything was fine.